# WSO2 APIM - Tunning

Tags: performance-testing, wso2-api-manager

I have performed some performance tests on WSO2 APIM on both WebServices (WSDL) and Gateway interfaces. Everything went good on the gateway one, however I am facing an odd behavior when using the WebServices one.

Basically I created a test that add, change password and delete a user and run a test plan using 64 threads. At the very beggining my throughput increases a lot up until reach all 64 threads (throughput peak was 1600 req/seg). However, after that the throughput start to decrease with no reason.

All 64 threads are still active and running, and the machine hosting the wso2am reduce CPU usage. It seems that APIM is given up of handling the request even though it has threads and processors for that.

The picture below shows the vmstat result for processor (user, system and idle) and the context switch and interruptions. It is possible to cpu/context switch follows the throughput.

[image]

And the next picture illustrate the jmeter test result after at the end (after decrease throughput).

[image]

Basically what I need is a clue on what may be the reason for such behavior. I have already tried to increase the pool of threads on both wso2am and tomcat, however it has no effect. It is like the requests were not arriving at all. Even though jmeter is full of power and had already send a bigger throughput before.

I would bet that a simple configuration on tomcat or wso2 is the answer for that. Any help is appreciate.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to JMeter not being able to send the requests fast enough, try the following steps:

- Upgrade JMeter to the latest version (3.1 as of now), you can get the most recent JMeter distribution from [JMeter download page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
- Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui). JMeter GUI can be used for tests development and/or debugging only, it is not designed for running load tests.
- Remove (or disable) all the [listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during test execution. Later on you can open JMeter GUI, add the listener of your choice, load .jtl results file and perform analysis or create an [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of results file

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for above points explained in details and few more tips on configuring JMeter for maximum performance and throughput

Comment: Dmitri, thanks you very much for your time. However that didn't change the result. I could reach 4K req/sec on the Gateway Interface and 2K req/sec on the Service Interface, on both cases the JMeter VM was using a bit of all available resources (cpu, i/o, mem, ...). The odd behavior is that for the Gateway Interface the throught is kept all over the test, but for the service one it starts high and keep getting down up until 10% of the peak usage.

Regards.